# Improve SELECT queries speed?

Tags: php, mysql

It take 40 seconds to display data on the browser, that is not unacceptable.

Code below, it display all the from category.takeawayID=xxxxx and loop in items and options tables.

categories table: over 15,000 rows total

items table: over 100,000 rows

item_options table: over 150,000 rows.

How to improve the performance?

```
 $qcat = mysql_query("select * from categories where takeawayID=55276");
 while($c_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qcat)) 
 {
     echo "<h2>" . $c_row['name'] . "</h2>";
     echo "<div>" . $c_row['description'] . "</div><br /> <br />";

     $qitem = mysql_query("select * from items where category_id =". $c_row['id']);

      while($i_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qitem)) {
           echo "<div style='backround-color:pink'>" . $i_row['name'] . "</div>";

           $qoption = mysql_query("select * from item_options where item_id =". $i_row['id']);

           while($o_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qoption)) {
               echo " (" . $o_row['price'] . ") ";
           }
      }
 }
```

Maximum records show between 200 to 500 rows depending on the takeawayID ID

Comment: they can be converted in to single query easily

Comment: Three nested selects is what we call a "Join".  MySQL can show you the execution plan.  From this you can figure out what indexes are required.   You should research the "Join" and the "Explain Plan" for MySQL first, then **update** your question with the single SELECT that you wrote which does a proper join and the plan which MySQL created for that SELECT.  Then we can comment on speed.  Until you write the join query, there's little to say except you need to write the proper SELECT.

Comment: And do you really need to show all 445 rows at same time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make an effort to create a single query using joins and also make sure you have created indexes on the columns.

```
select * from categories c 
left join items t
on c.id= t.category_id
left join item_options io 
on t.id=io.item_id
Where c.takeawayID=55276
```

Comment: But how you would seperate the category name and items name, and options prices for layout view? options and items can have more than 1

Comment: @user622378: Of course, You have to write the logic to display data, if you keep these 3 level nested loop it will always take time

Answer (score 2):

General hints:

- Use `EXPLAIN` to profile how efficient your queries are
- `SELECT *` is inefficient. Only `SELECT` the fields you need.
- Create indexes on the fields within the tables in question to improve speed

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have table indexes on categories.takeawayID, items.category_id and item_options.item_id

Comment: That won't make a big difference while he has three levels of nested queries.

Comment: But I have read that indexes would effect performance when adding and deleting rows? Agents will be adding/editing data everyday at the backend.

Comment: The performance degradation from proper indexing will be unnoticeable to your users... you've already seen how slow things can be without indexes. Your three levels of nested query are causing the real problem, and you should fix that to use joins first, but indexing will also help

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider -

You probably don't need to `SELECT *` from any table. Select only what you need will help.

Also consider limiting the number of results (use pagination if needed), as it seems unlikely you would need to output 15,000 items in a single go.

Without knowing your table structure, it's hard to say how, but you could make use of `JOIN` rather than looping through masses of data in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

Stop doing the subquery in a loop within your code.  You can return the master-detail information in a single query that joins items and item_options.  Sort the result by item_id, so that you can dump out your background-color change when a new item_id is traversed.